# Let $X$ be an integrable RV with median $m$. Show that $m=\text{argmin}_a\mathbb{E}|X-a|$

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

I have tried to look for mistakes in these calculations until I turned blue, but still clueless. If anyone could help me pointing out the errors, I would be really grateful.

My apology for the long post, I hope it is not hard to read through. Let me know if anything is unclear :)

> Let $X$ be an integrable RV with median $m$. Show that $m=\text{argmin}_a\mathbb{E}|X-a|$.

My attempt:
Using the facts $\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^\infty(1-F_X(x))dx$ and $|X|=X^++X^-$, and the DFs for $X^\pm$:
$$F_+(t)= \begin {cases} 0&\text{if }t < 0;\\
F(t)&\text{if }t \ge 0. \end {cases}$$
$$F_-(t)= \begin {cases} 0&\text{if }t < 0;\\
1-F(-t)&\text{if }t \ge 0. \end {cases}$$

we write 
$$\mathbb{E}|X-a|=\mathbb{E}X_a^++X_a^-\text{, where }X_a:=X-a$$
$$=\int_0^\infty(1-F_{X_a^+}(t))dt+\int_0^\infty(1-F_{X_a^-}(t))dt$$

> But $F_{X_a^+}(t)=F_{X_a}(t)=\mathbb{P}(X_a \le t)=\mathbb{P}(X-a\le t)=\mathbb{P}(X\le t+a)=F_x(t+a)$ and $F_{X_a^-}(t)=1-F_{X_a}(-t)=1-\mathbb{P}(X_a \le -t)=1-\mathbb{P}(X-a\le -t)$ 
>   $$=1-\mathbb{P}(X\le a-t)$$ 
>   $$=1-F_x(a-t)$$

So,
$$=\int_0^\infty(1-F_x(t+a))dt+\int_0^\infty F_x(a-t)dt$$
then perform the change of variable $u=t+a,v=a-t$
$$=\int_a^\infty(1-F_x(u))du+\int_a^{-\infty} F_x(v)dv$$
$$=\int_a^\infty(1-F_x(u))du-\int_{-\infty}^a F_x(v)dv$$
then take the derivative w.r.t. a and set =0
$$\frac{d}{da}\int_a^\infty(1-F_x(u))du-\int_{-\infty}^a F_x(v)dv$$
$$=-(1-F_x(a))-F_x(a)=0$$
then I got into trouble since $F_x(a)$ cancels each other.

**When I looked at the solution, I believe there are some miscalculations but somehow they get the correct answer (i.e. they have shown that a=m).**

Here is the solution:
$$\mathbb{E}|X-a|=\mathbb{E}X_a^++X_a^-$$
$$=\int_0^\infty(1-F_{X_a^+}(t))dt+\int_0^\infty(1-F_{X_a^-}(t))dt$$

> but they arrive in a different expression for $F_{X_a^-}(t)$, they get $F_{X_a^-}(t)=1-F_x(-(t+a))$
>   so,
>   $$=\int_0^\infty(1-F_x(t+a))dt+\int_0^\infty F_x(-(t+a))dt$$
>   changing variables: $u=t+a$
>   $$=\int_a^\infty(1-F_x(u))du+\int_{-\infty}^a F_x(u)du$$

to minimise this expression in a,
$$\frac{d}{da}\int_a^\infty(1-F_x(u))du+\int_{-\infty}^a F_x(u)du=0$$
Solving for a,
$$-(1-F_x(a))+F_x(a)=0$$
$$F_x(a)=1-F_x(a)$$
$$\implies F_x(a)=1/2$$
so $a=m$.

> What I am really doubtful about is how they arrived in $F_{X_a^-}(t)=1-F_x(-(t+a))$. I have no idea how they got that.
>
> Also, I couldn't follow their change of variables, how did they get from $\int_0^\infty F_x(-(t+a))dt$ to $\int_{-\infty}^a F_x(u)du$. How did they take the minus sign out of the integral?

I would be extremely grateful if anyone could help me on this. Many sincere thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use informative, descriptive titles - searching the site won't be useful to people if everything is titled "*What am I doing wrong*" or "*How to solve this*" or things like that.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks for your reminder.